# How can I pass the callback to another StatefulWidget?

Tags: dart, flutter

For example, I have two StatefulWidget to monitor the same callback method. How should I do this? In case I have more than three StatefulWidget to monitor its events?

```
class WidgetOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetOneState createState() => new _WidgetOneState();
}

class _WidgetOneState extends State<WidgetOne> {

  // this is the callback, the widget two want listen the callback too
  bool _onNotification(ScrollNotification notification){

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new NotificationListener(child: new ListView(shrinkWrap: true,),
          onNotification: _onNotification),
        new WidgetTwo()
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WidgetTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetTwoState createState() => new _WidgetTwoState();
}

class _WidgetTwoState extends State<WidgetTwo> {

  // in this,How Can I get the callback in WidgetOne?
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution could be possible by using `setState()` and pass your state function in constructor of WidgetTwo. I did an example below, main idea of this example is I have **MyHomePage** as my main Widget and **MyFloatButton** (which I want to customise as another `StatefulWidget`), so when pressing the FAB i need to call increment counter function in MyHomePage. Lets take a look below how I do that.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  //Consider this function as your's _onNotification and important to note I am using setState() within :)
  void _incrementCounter() { 
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button $_counter times:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new MyFloatButton(_incrementCounter),//here I am calling MyFloatButton Constructor passing _incrementCounter as a function
    );
  }
}

class MyFloatButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function onPressedFunction;

  // Here I am receiving the function in constructor as params
  MyFloatButton(this.onPressedFunction);

  @override
  _MyFloatButtonState createState() => new _MyFloatButtonState();
}

class _MyFloatButtonState extends State<MyFloatButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orangeAccent, borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
      child: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: widget.onPressedFunction,// here i set the onPressed property with widget.onPressedFunction. Remember that you should use "widget." in order to access onPressedFunction here!
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now Consider MyHomePage as your WidgetOne, MyFloatButton as your WidgetTwo and _incrementCounter function as your _onNotification. Hope you will achieve what you want :)

(I did example generically so anyone can understand according to scenario they are facing)

Comment: Your example shows that the child is passed from the child component to the parent component, which I know, but my case is that the callback function of the parent component is passed to the child component. X

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't. Widgets should never depends on the architecture of other widgets.

You have two possibilities :

- Merge `WidgetTwo` and `WidgetOne`. As separating them doesn't makes sense (at least with what you provided).
- Modify `WidgetTwo` to take a child. And add that `ListView` as child of `WidgetTwo`. So that it can wrap the list into it's own `NotificationListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `widget` property for stateful widgets.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html

So in `WidgetOne` it will be

```
new WidgetTwo(callback: callback)
```

in `WidgetTwo`

```
class WidgetTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callback;
  
  WidgetTwo({this.callback});


  @override
  _WidgetTwoState createState() => new _WidgetTwoState();
}
```

and in `_WidgetTwoState` you can access it as

```
widget.callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is defining a callback interface inside the child component and use it to notify the parent component. An example below, where the `class OutagesScreen extends StatefulWidget` is the parent component and the `class PrefecturesDropdown extends StatefulWidget` is the child component.

Inside the child component, define a callback interface. That is:

```
typedef PrefectureDtoCallback = PrefectureDto Function(PrefectureDto);
```

On the constructor of the child component, define the callback that is expected such as follows:

```
  /// Callback to return the selected prefecture to the parent component.
  final PrefectureDtoCallback currentPrefectureCallback;
  const PrefecturesDropdown(this.currentPrefectureCallback, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
```

Now upon an action on the child component you can notify via the defined callback the parent component. On this example, we're notifying about a new selected prefecture:

```
      onChanged: (PrefectureDto? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          defaultPrefecture = newValue!;
          widget.currentPrefectureCallback(
              newValue); // Notify about the new selected prefecture.
        });
      }
```

Now, on the parent component you can receive the notification as follows:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getOutages(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: [
              PrefecturesDropdown((value) {
                // Receive the notification
                return selectedPrefecture = value;
              }),
              Flexible(
                child: outagesList(context),
              )
            ]),
          );
        }
```

You can find a full working example of this on [GitHub: Black Out](https://github.com/gbrandtio/black-out). The specific files you can the implementation discussed here are `outages.dart` (parent component) and `prefectures_dropdown.dart` (child component).